# native client curl library linking

Tags: curl, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to use native client (pNaCl) with the curl library from naclports. I have NaCl SDK version 38 and I'm using the pepper_38 branch of naclports. After successfully building the curl library, I included the header in my project and executed "make" with the pnacl toolchain. If only the header is included all goes well, but as soon as I try to use a curl function from the library, I get a ton of "undefined reference" errors inside that library:

```
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'sigaction'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'recv'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'getsockname'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'bind'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'getsockopt'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'socket'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'connect'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'htons'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'getpeername'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'inet_pton'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'ntohs'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'inet_ntop'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'setsockopt'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'poll'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'send'
/nacl_sdk/pepper_38/toolchain/linux_pnacl/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
```

I'm completely new to NaCl, so any tips would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to compile my project. In the end it came down to the order in which the libraries were linked. The working order turned out to be the following: ppapi_cpp ppapi pthread curl ssl crypto z nacl_io. The first 3 were already in the sample project, the others were added.

Comment: I'm on pepper_49 and built curl using google's webports on the pepper_49 bramcj, libcurl.a gives me `error: undefined reference to 'alarm'`, any idea?  The problem goes away if I also add `glibc-compat`, but curl doesn't work at all if that library is added.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing some libraries on your link line. In particular, most of them seem to be socket calls. These functions are defined in the nacl_io library.

In most toolchains these functions are defined in your C library, so you don't have to link any additional libraries. But in NaCl (when using the newlib library), there are many missing functions that are added by nacl_io.

It looks like you need inflate as well, which comes from the zlib library. So you're new link line should look like this:

```
<other link args> -lcurl -lz -lnacl_io -lppapi
```

libppapi.a is needed because the nacl_io library uses it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already had zlib and ppapi, so I added nacl_io, but I got the exact same error output. (also to note I only posted a small portion of it yesterday, because the output was too long. It's basically like I get the undefined reference on every single function/object in libcurl).

Not sure if this is important, but I'm using the "part 2" example from the getting_started folder in the SDK. I added curl to the Makefile and tried to use it in the code.